# How do I make a dynamic custom keyboard Android ? (programmatically)

Tags: android, dynamic, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I try to create a keyboard from string ArrayList (not only char) but no one constructor of the object Keyboard allows it.

Keyboard | Android Developers :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html

Source code :

```
    mKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard, "", 10, 0);

    Keyboard.Row row = new Keyboard.Row(mKeyboard);
    row.defaultHeight = 108;
    row.defaultWidth = 150;
    row.defaultHorizontalGap = 0;
    row.verticalGap = 0;
    row.rowEdgeFlags = mKeyboard.EDGE_BOTTOM | mKeyboard.EDGE_TOP;

    Keyboard.Key key = new Keyboard.Key(row);
    key.x = 0;
    key.y = 0;
    key.codes = new int[]{1};
    key.label = "test";

    Keyboard.Key key1 = new Keyboard.Key(row);
    key1.x = 150;
    key1.y = 0;
    key1.width = 300;
    key1.codes = new int[]{2};
    key1.label = "test1";

    mKeyboard.getKeys().add(key);
    mKeyboard.getKeys().add(key1);
```

I don't have access to the properties to change keyboard dimensions.

Does anyone has a solution to my problem ?